# How do I use OutputBucketName in python 3 for amazon transcribe

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-transcribe

Hi All first post help greatly appreciated

I have looked everywhere on the internet and tried guessing how to use it with no answer to this question

Thanks

Question: How do I use OutputBucketName in python 3 for amazon transcribe

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [mcve] so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your Amazon S3 Bucket name in the following way:

```
response = client.start_transcription_job(
TranscriptionJobName='string',
LanguageCode='en-US',
MediaSampleRateHertz=123,
MediaFormat='mp4',
Media={
    'MediaFileUri': 'string'
},
OutputBucketName='string')
```

Please refer to document: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/transcribe.html#TranscribeService.Client.start_transcription_job

And also: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-transcribe-now-lets-you-designate-your-own-amazon-s3-buckets-to-store-transcription-outputs/